# Show posts other than current post on Show Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, ruby-on-rails-4

This is probably an easy question, but can't find it for the life of me..

On a post's show action, I'm trying to show in a small sidebar all of the other posts of that user besides the current post. Im using a loop with

```
@post.user.posts.limit(6).shuffle.each do
```

i would think you could do

```
.except(@post)
```

or something similar to exclude the current post but that didn't do the trick. Does anyone know how to do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do it via SQL:

```
@post.user.posts.where("posts.id <> ?", @post.id).limit(6).shuffle.each do
# same thing but wrote differently:
@post.user.posts.where("posts.id NOT IN (?)", @post.id).limit(6).shuffle.each do
```

Comment: Op op opa gangnam style!

Comment: Actually listening to **Distrubed - Deify** right now @Sparda ;-)

Comment: haha that did work MrYoshji...thanks...last time we spoke you were at 10K rep...you've been doing work haha

Comment: @Justin yes you're right, I'm addicted to this reputation earning system... Ahah